# How can I create a variable sized UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, cs193p

I can't seem to get the text to actually span multiple lines. The heights look correct. What am I missing?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell =  [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"StatusCell"] autorelease];

    CGRect frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    myLabel.text = [[person.updates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"text"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];

    [myLabel release];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *text = [[person.updates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"text"];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    CGSize withinSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, 1000);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:withinSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return size.height + 20;    
}
```

Also, what am I missing that makes the labels appear longer than the table cell?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Tweetero` provides an example of this in [`MessageListController.m`](http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/source/browse/trunk/Classes/MessageListController.m).  The code there renders the following screen:

[image]

(Pic is taken from [Mashable](http://mashable.com/2009/04/20/tweetero/)).

The basic implementation outline:

1. When constructing a `UITableViewCell`, create and add a `UILabel` as a subview in the manner shown in `tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifier:`.  Look for the creation of `TEXT_TAG` label.
2. when enriching the `UITableViewCell` with views, ensure that you format label properly, as is done in `configureCell:forIndexPath`, similarly look for the label tag `TEXT_TAG`.
3. Return the appropriate height for each cell, as is done in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 2):

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Check the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines) for full info on how to use this property.

Comment: the problem is that it won't always be a specific number, it will change for each row

Comment: The numberOfLines property sets the **maximum** number of lines. Set it to a high value. (And, as Rob said, check the docs.)

Comment: You also have to set the myLabel.lineBrakeMode to UILineBreakModeWordWrap.

Comment: Setting it to 0 means "no maximum." @Nikolai's right about lineBreakMode; I had in my head that WordWrap was the default for UILabel, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return theSizeYouWantYourCellToBe;
}
```